# Rows Created by JS did not adapte to css

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why when I add manually a hardcoded row to my table, the generated ones fit well on the table, but when I populate the table directly by generated rows it shows wrong.

The same CSS are applied so why its happening?

Eg 1(Good):

[image]

Eg 2(Wrong):

[image]

Html:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
<div class="panel panel-default">           
<table class="table table-hover table.size">
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </td>
      <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>           
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  var row =
        "<td>"
           + "<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;'>Bob</a>"
        + "</td>"
        + "<td class='text-right text-nowrap'>"
           +"<button class='btn btn-xs btn-info'>edit</button>"
           +" <button class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>"
              +"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>"
           +"</button>"
        +  "</td>"

        var trow = document.createElement("tr");
        trow.innerHTML = row;

        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(trow);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second image? if you want the table to be full-width, you will need to specify that in css.

Comment: it is probably because with the text in the first example, the text being longer, the first column expands at max for it to fit (until max and then word wrap). Being a table, all the column expands width, even for other rows. Try to add longer text to generated rows, it should be the same

Comment: Still the same, even with hardcoded rows and short text the row takes all the space and text is centred ?

Comment: when I copy this in jsfiddle it works fine. do u have your code somewhere hosted? https://jsfiddle.net/6t02rkoh/

Comment: Wow I see, my code is just in a file and I'm in localhost on Chrome

Comment: I want to add a class to my : var trow = document.createElement("tr"). I thought about trow.addClass("table.size") to expand row to max width.